# Returning to a URL when in an MVC action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I Have the following code but it gives an error message:

```
                var url = (string) Session["CurrentUrl"];
                if (url != null)
                {
                    var ip = new Uri(url);
                    var ipNoPort = string.Format("{0}://{1}/{2}", ip.Scheme, ip.Host, ip.PathAndQuery);
                    return RedirectResult(ipNoPort);
                }
                return View();
```

The error points to RedirectResult saying Error 1   'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectResult' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: What's the value of taking the url string, converting it to a URI, and then making it back into a string (possibly incorrectly)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return new RedirectResult(ipNoPort);
```

I think you're confusing it with

```
return RedirectToRoute("Home");
```

Which is a member of the controller.